# Python: Convert 2-digit / 4-digit year

Tags: python, date, time, python-datetime, strptime

I am trying to convert the date format '31-Dec-09' to '2009-12-31' in Python with the following code:

```
df = ['19-Jan-19', '4-Jan-19']   
f = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%d-%mmm-%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in df]
print(f)
```

Getting the following error:

```
time data '9-Jan-19' does not match format '%d-%mmm-%y'
```

I have read somewhere that matching a two-digit year '00' would require a lowercase y instead of an upper case one. Either way, I am getting the same error so I guess something else is wrong. Any help?

Comment: Do read the [documentation for `strptime()` carefully](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), Python `strptime()` doesn't use repeated characters.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `%y` and `%Y` patterns are fine, the issue is that you used `%mmm` here. The `datetime.strptime()` method patterns are all *single letter* patterns, and `%mmm` is seen as the `%m` pattern followed by two literal `m` characters. `%m` matches a numeric month (1 or 2 digits, zero-padding optional). So `19-1mm-19` would match, but `19-Jan-19` does not because the month is not numeric and the two literal `m` characters are missing.

The correct pattern to use is `'%d-%b-%y'` here, where `%b` matches an abbreviated month name.

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> df = ['19-Jan-19', '4-Jan-19']
>>> [datetime.datetime.strptime(x,'%d-%b-%y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for x in df]
['2019-01-19', '2019-01-04']
```

Comment: How can I convert "23-08-00" to "23-08-2000" or "13-05-01" to "13-01-2001" ? Which are Dates in the 1st column of the .csv...

Comment: Does anyone read my comment?

Answer (score 4):

Since you're specifying month in short hand notation, you should use %b instead of %mmm (That is not a valid format in datetime)